# Query to get data from 3 different table for different keys with count

Tags: mysql, sql

### user table

```
userName | email(p.k) | accountType(p.k)

Vivek    | v@asd.asd  | google
Rahul    | r@asd.asd  | facebook
Rohit    | r@amd.asd  | google
```

### event table

```
eventId(p.k) | email(f.k) | accountType(f.k) | eventName

    1        | v@asd.asd  |      google      | birthday
```

### contributer

```
eventId(f.k) | email(f.k) | accountType(f.k) | contribute

    1        | r@asd.asd  |     facebook     |     $20
    1        | r@amd.asd  |      google      |     $30
```

I want the Result data like

### Result

```
userName contribute  name    count  eventName
 Rahul       $20     Vivek     2    birthday
 Rohit       $30     Vivek     2    birthday


rahul contribute $20 for vivek birthday 2 contributer are there for this event
rohit contribute $30 for vivek birthday 2 contributer are there for this event
```

query what i use

```
SELECT 
uc.userName as cName, 
uc.email as cEmail, 
uc.accountType as cAccType,
contribute, 
u.userName as userName,
u.email as email, 
u.accountType as accountType,
eventName 
FROM user u 
join event e on u.email=e.email and u.accountType=e.accountType 
join contributer c on c.eventId=e.eventId 
join user uc on c.email=uc.email and c.accountType=uc.accountType
```

and some thing like this

```
SELECT * 
FROM user
JOIN contribute ON user.email = contribute.email
JOIN event ON event.id = contribute._eventId
JOIN user u2 ON event.email = u2.email;
```

How to fetch both the data with count in the same query can any one please help me out

Comment: Mysql, Oracle or both?

Comment: any thing  mysql help me a lot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

by adding **(select count(eventId) from contributor where eventId = e.eventId)** it help me a lot.

```
SELECT 
uc.userName as cName, 
uc.email as cEmail, 
uc.accountType as cAccType,
c.contribute, 
u.userName as userName,
u.email as email, 
u.accountType as accountType,
e.eventName ,
(select count(eventId) from contributor where eventId = e.eventId)
FROM user u 
join event e on u.email=e.email and u.accountType=e.accountType 
join contributer c on c.eventId=e.eventId 
join user uc on c.email=uc.email and c.accountType=uc.accountType
```

Answer (score 0):

**USE SUBQUERY:**

```
    select user_name,(select contribute from contributer   
     where email = usr.email) as contribute,(select user_name from user_table where email = (select email   
    from event_table where event_id = (select event_id from contributer where email = usr.email))) as name,(select count(event_id) from contributer 
where event_id = (select event_id from contributer 
where email = usr.email)) as count from user_table as usr
```

**result:**

```
userName contribute  name    count

Vivek     NULL        NULL    0

Rahul     $20         Vivek   2

Rohit     $30         Vivek   2
```

Comment: thanks for your suggestion adding (select count(eventId) from contributor where eventId = e.eventId) help me with that

Answer (score 0):

As users appear twice in the result, you have to use that table twice - once as a contributor, and another time as a person being honored at a celebration.

Something like this (Oracle):

```
SQL> with t_user (username, email, accounttype) as
  2    (select 'vivek', 'v@asd.asd', 'google'       from dual union
  3     select 'rahul', 'r@asd.asd', 'facebook'     from dual union
  4     select 'rohit', 'r@amd.asd', 'google'       from dual
  5    ),
  6  t_event (eventid, email, accounttype, eventname) as
  7    (select 1, 'v@asd.asd', 'google', 'birthday' from dual),
  8  t_contributer (eventid, email, accounttype, contribute) as
  9    (select 1, 'r@asd.asd', 'facebook', '$20'    from dual union
 10     select 1, 'r@amd.asd', 'google'  , '$30'    from dual)
 11  select
 12    t1.username || ' contribute ' ||      c.contribute   ||
 13    ' for '     || t2.username    ||' '|| e.eventname    ||' ' ||
 14    count(*) over (partition by c.eventid order by null) ||
 15    ' contributer for this week' result
 16  from t_contributer c join t_event e on c.eventid = e.eventid
 17  join t_user t1 on t1.email = c.email
 18  join t_user t2 on t2.email = e.email;

RESULT
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
rahul contribute $20 for vivek birthday 2 contributer for this week
rohit contribute $30 for vivek birthday 2 contributer for this week

SQL>
```

Comment: can you please change this into mysql

Comment: No, as I don't speak MySQL. Hm, where did the "Oracle" tag go? It was here yesterday.

Comment: thanks for your support and sorry for that,@Gordon Linoff has been removied that tag

Comment: You're welcome. I hope you'll manage to convert it to MySQL. Basically, all you need starts at line 11 in my example. Problem might be the COUNT analytic function (if MySQL doesn't have it).

Comment: If it does what you wanted, great.